# iphone - Setting the starting tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to set the starting controller in a tab bar controller not as the 1st one (not as the first tab icon on the tab bar), but as the 3rd one (3rd icon on a 4-icon tab bar)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. In code/xib you have to set  `tabBarController`s ' `selectedIndex` property as `2`.
(index starts from 0)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can do it easily....just use this ,You can do it either programmatically or in Xib file

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```